# Where can I see a summary of tools and techniques for most updated transformer developments?

Tags: nlp, transformer, gpt

Since the invention of chatGPT, there are many tools and techniques and variants invented ever since. I want to keep track of these developments and tools but I find no avail. May I know which resources/sites that showcases all these? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great place to start and gives you the top level: https://github.com/Hannibal046/Awesome-LLM

If you really want to keep up technically I suggest a regular perusal of:
https://arxiv.org/list/cs/recent as things change quickly these days.